# Deleted users persists in database in liferay 6.1.0 CE

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

From Liferay GUI first i deactivate user and then delete deactivate user but  looking in the database i see that the deleted user still there,and i will not able to add again some deleted user from GUI.

I am usig liferay version 6.1.0 CE and mysql 5.1.71.

Please help me how can i delete user permanently from GUI as well as from database.

Comment: are you sure you are referrring to User_ table

Comment: hope you don't have any hook configured for User. Also did you try the latest 6.1 CE GA3 version, it has a lot of bug fixes. I also hope that you are seeing the correct table in the correct schema. If the User is there in the database table you can see the User on the UI or try re-indexing and see if you can see the deleted user on UI to confirm.

Comment: In the log-file you can follow when by deleting or creating of user some fail. Log-file is by unix or linux server: `~/portal/tomcat/logs/catalina.out`

Comment: I refer User_ table, After re-indexing i saw again Deleted user as an inactive user in GUI. Actually i used Userid column from User_ table as a foreign Key in another table for mapping, when i delete mapping(with user) in another table from database and then after i delete user from GUI it also deleted from User_ table...there is any way to change delete method code to delete user from all table in which it is used..